# get custom post type value in header.php

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the ACF plugin for custom posts types and am fairly new to using it. I have a field called "app_url" that is a url that I need to include as a link in my header.php file so it is on all pages, the custom post type is called "slider". If I just use

```
<a><?php get_field('app_url'); ?></>
```

It doesn't work. I also tried

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'slider');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      <a><?php get_field('app_url'); ?></>
  endwhile; ?>
```

which gives me a blank page. I'm fairly new to the concept of loops and am wondering if you can even have a loop in a header if there is another one in the page.php content and maybe that's why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm observing three problems here.

### 1- Your anchors do not have a `href` attribute.

As you mentioned, the `app_url` field is a URL, and should be output in the `href` attribute of an anchor. So, this is how your anchor should look like:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_field( 'app_url' ) ); ?>">My Link</a>
```

Note that I've also escaped the value by using the [`esc_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) function, to eliminate invalid characters.

### 2- The `get_field()` function accepts a post ID.

The second parameter of the [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) function accepts a post ID. So, let's pass it to the function in the loop:

```
<?php 

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'slider');
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
            $loop->the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_field( 'app_url', get_the_ID() ) ); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a><?php
        endwhile; 

?>
```

### 3- You forgot to use the PHP tags

Note that you didn't have opening and closing PHP tags around your anchors in the loop ( The `<?php` and `?>` tags ), and there was a missing `a` in your closing `</a>` tag.

Comment: many thanks, that works perfectly and I see where I made my mistakes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**You can also try this coding  to fetch the post-type module according to Ascending(ASC) or Descending(DESC):-**

```
<?php
  $args=array(
      'post_type' => 'slider',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'posts_per_page' => -1
  );
  $myposts = null;
  $myposts = new WP_Query($args);
  if( $myposts->have_posts() ) {
  $i=0;
      while ($myposts->have_posts()) : $myposts->the_post();
      $i=$i+1;
      ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_field('app_url'); ?>">link</a>
      <!-- or -->
      <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_field( 'app_url' ) ); ?>"> link</a>
  <?php
      endwhile;
  }
  ?>
```